# Getting Cat ID when product is in multiple Cats magento

Tags: magento, cat

Only problem I have : I want to make a link on the product page :/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml

to the Category the products belong. I can get this gixed by

Problem ;

Most of products are in multiple Categories. I have 1 map in the root with the "Brands", so the url = /all_brands/brand

So product_a is in the list of eg : BrandA

But some products are also listed in for example the map Weeoffers (in Root) /weekoffer/

How can I determine the correct ID , If I want only to have the BRAND ID in de the url ?

id_path="all_brands/22" ?

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain current category from registry by invoking `Mage::registry('current_category')` . By default this will work as you expected only on `CATALOG PAGE` and `PRODUCT PAGE`

If you're viewing product, and you want to get category of viewed category you can use `Mage::registry('current_category')->getId();`.

Of course it will be wise if you ensure that `current_category` isn't null :)